# Ethereum for private enterprise network

Tags: private-blockchain

If I want to build commercial blockchain applications, do I need to join to the main ethereum network? or I just can build ethereum private enterprise blockchain? by creating some peers?

What is the benefit to join the main network if I have to pay fees for each transaction? is it only to exchange real ethers?

And why main ethereum network is more more protected and secured?

Comment: See answered question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/378/what-usecases-do-private-blockchains-have and also its linked/related questions

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to build commercial blockchain applications, do I need to
>   join to the main ethereum network? or I just can build ethereum
>   private enterprise blockchain? by creating some peers?

Yes, you can create your own private enterprise blockchain by connecting peers in one network.

> What is the benefit to join the main network if I have to pay fees for
>   each transaction? is it only to exchange real ethers?

By joining public ethereum blockchain , your DAPP(Decentralised Application) is accessible to all the users of public blockchain. In case of private blockchain only nodes which are connected in a private network can participate. So if you are okay with restricted and limited user base , you should go with private blockchain.

The following blog addresses all the [pros and cons of private and public blockchain](http://yogibetsur.blogspot.in/2018/04/blockchain-education-series-part-2.html)

Hope this will help !