# Offline transaction like lightening network on Ethereum

Tags: web3js, transactions, raw-transaction, internal-transactions, offline

I want to implement transaction process like lightening network.
When 2 people do number of transactions between each other, for instance they did 10 transaction with each other. I want to keep all this to be offline and once they both want to settle down, the final transaction will publish on network instead of all the 10 transaction.
How can i achieve/implement this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to do that? I want the functionality like lightening network in Ethereum

Comment: Search for state channels, for example https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/473/what-are-state-channels-and-use-case-code-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the functionality like lightening network in Ethereum

See Raiden Network: https://raiden.network